# What are different ways of creating a webpart in Office 365 these days?

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, office-365

Last time I was working on SharePoint Online, there were 3 types of apps one could create, provider hosted etc.

What options are available now a days and preferred for Office 365 only?

Answer (score 1):

Office 365 SharePoint Online supports development using:

1. [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview) - [Web parts](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/overview-client-side-web-parts) and [Extensions](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/overview-extensions).
2. [SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-add-ins) - [SharePoint Hosted](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins) and [Provided Hosted](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/get-started-creating-provider-hosted-sharepoint-add-ins).
3. [SharePoint webhooks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/apis/webhooks/overview-sharepoint-webhooks).